# aws - needed requirements - windows - sqlserver - webapp

Tags: sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a totally newbie with cloud computing, but I want to try it.

I want to relocate a public app developed by myself and currently served by a traditional hosting.

The requirements are just the basics. 
- Windows Server 2008 R2 or later

- minimal ram
- .net 2.0 and .net 4.0 support
- IIS
- SQL Server 2008
- Some 20gb, for the app, db, and files
- Some 10gb more (DB backup)

With win2 + sql server I can't use the free testing. I know that and I'm ready to pay the platform needed. In the current hosting I'm paying for that too.

I just want see if someone can validate my configuration and say if I'm forgetting something:

- 1 instance EC2 Windows and Std. SQL Server m4.large
- 1 Amazon EBS Volumes 100gb, 3IOPS, 30% snapshots
- 1 Elastic IP for the unique instance
- 5GB Transfer in, out, interdata

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&s=EC2&key=calc-D29B73A3-A7C5-4CEE-9C4F-3ED5A74D2420

Basically, the server will run the web app who has connection with the database installed in the same machine (maybe in the future with more visits the db will be moved to another vm). The web app will be public access.

Someone see something missing?
Should I buy amazon s3 storage for the backups? 
Where will be saved the ebs volume backups? or with my configuration I can't have backups?

At the moment I'll keep using my own dns server and I hope be capable to configure for redirect to aws without need of amazon route 53.

at are you seeing, I need some orientation, because I'm a little lost in this new world. What services I need?  what about the backups?

I'm not thinking at this moment in optimization (cache, load balance, ...). If the things go in the right way, in the future. Right now I just want the most simply installation. My problem, windows and sql, those can't be used in free version and I can't change the app.

I feel shame for be so annoying, but I still have those doubts.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of pieces to this. I will try and break some of it down.

> Should I buy amazon s3 storage for the backups? Where will be saved
> the ebs volume backups? or with my configuration I can't have backups?

You can script a backup of the drive to S3, or back up the volume entirely as a 'volume'. Totally up to you. Backing up contents of the drive to S3 with a proper script (like [this](http://www.rhysgodfrey.co.uk/b/blog/archive/2014/10/06/backing-up-a-sql-database-to-amazon-s3-using-powershell)) would be a great idea.

> At the moment I'll keep using my own dns server and I hope be capable to configure for redirect to aws without need of amazon route 53.

Route 53 is amazing and an extremely small charge for the flexibility it gives. I would recommend using it because it ties in neatly to other AWS services you might need (like load balancers) in the future.

> I just want see if someone can validate my configuration and say if I'm forgetting something:
>
> 1 instance EC2 Windows and Std. SQL Server m4.large
>
> 1 Amazon EBS Volumes 100gb, 3IOPS, 30% snapshots
>
> 1 Elastic IP for the unique instance
>
> 5GB Transfer in, out, interdata

With an m4.large, you get 2 VCPUs and 8gb of memory, and 450mbps throughput. Do you need all that horsepower? You can try a t2.medium if that sounds like a lot for some burstable cpu performance. It all depends on what utilization you're at now, and if you're CPU/memory/bandwidth bound.

Feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

For backups of EBS volumes to S3, the best way to backup would be us EBS snapshots.